# Loading JSON in canvas with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, json, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to save data in JSON and load it back into the canvas with **fabric.js** I keep getting errors likep with the following simple code:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: 'red', top: 100, left: 100 }));
var c = canvas.toJSON();
canvas.clear();
canvas.loadFromJSON(c);
```

I get:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
[Break On This Error] var Cufon=(function(){var k=function()....Image.fromElement.async=true})(this);
```

When I use my own JSON, It validates well, but I still get errors when I use whatever was output by fabric's method canvas.toJSON(). Anyone would have working examples of loading back into an empty canvas data saved from a previous canvas state in fabric.js? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`fabric.Canvas#toJSON` actually returns an object, not a JSON string.

Sorry, if this is confusing.

The reason this works like that is due to `JSON.stringify`. The thing about `JSON.stringify` is that it supports custom serialization; all you need to do is pass an object that has `toJSON` method. And this is exactly what I did in fabric — fabric.Canvas has `toJSON` method, which is essentially an alias to `toObject` method.

This allows us to serialize canvas by doing something as simple as:

```
JSON.stringify(canvas);
```

.. where `canvas` is a reference to `fabric.Canvas` instance.

The difference between `toObject` and `toDatalessObject` (as well as `toJSON` and `toDatalessJSON`) is that `toDatalessObject` returns "url" instead of actual path data. This is done to save on size of canvas representation with shapes of large size. If you load large SVG shape, its path data could literally result in multi-million character string. If you later need to serialize this data (say, for saving purposes), it makes much more sense to replace path data with URL of svg shape. Just imagine having to upload/download such huge strings to the server back and forth.

So, instead of this:

```
{ "angle" : 3,
  "fill" : "#00274D",
  "flipX" : false,
  "flipY" : false,
  "height" : 115,
  "left" : 353,
  "opacity" : 1,
  "overlayFill" : null,
  "path" : [ [ "M",
        67.390000000000001,
        22.390000000000001
      ],
      [ "c",
        2.5899999999999999,
        -0.42999999999999999,
        5.1100000000000003,
        1.4399999999999999,
        5.54,
        4.1799999999999997
      ],
      [ "c",
        0.42999999999999999,
        2.6600000000000001,
        -1.3,
        5.2599999999999998,
        -3.8900000000000001,
        5.6900000000000004
      ],
      [ "c",
        -1.8,
        0.28999999999999998,
        -3.6000000000000001,
        -0.57999999999999996,
        -4.6100000000000003,
        -2.02
      ],
      [ "L",
        44.5,
        34.560000000000002
      ],
      [ "l",
        10.869999999999999,
        59.619999999999997
      ],
      [ "c",
        17.420000000000002,
        -4.46,
        26.059999999999999,
        -14.18,
        27.5,
        -29.02
      ],
      [ "l",
        -10.01,
        -0.71999999999999997
      ],
      [ "L",
        88.700000000000003,
        51.909999999999997
      ],
      [ "l",
        9.4299999999999997,
        21.239999999999998
      ],
      [ "c",
        -3.3799999999999999,
        -1.95,
        -5.9000000000000004,
        -5.1100000000000003,
        -9.2899999999999991,
        -7.0599999999999996
      ],
      [ "c",
        -0.28999999999999998,
        25.059999999999999,
        -27.140000000000001,
        32.759999999999998,
        -33.770000000000003,
        47.950000000000003
      ],
      [ "C",
        44.420000000000002,
        100.08,
        26.5,
        114.77,
        6.9100000000000001,
        82.799999999999997
      ],
      [ "L",
        0,
        92.450000000000003
      ],
      [ "l",
        1.51,
        -21.600000000000001
      ],
      [ "l",
        19.66,
        4.6799999999999997
      ],
      [ "l",
        -9.4299999999999997,
        3.6699999999999999
      ],
      [ "c",
        7.4900000000000002,
        11.59,
        17.57,
        19.870000000000001,
        36.43,
        16.420000000000002
      ],
      [ "L",
        36.219999999999999,
        36.57
      ],
      [ "l",
        -18.649999999999999,
        2.3799999999999999
      ],
      [ "c",
        -0.14000000000000001,
        2.1600000000000001,
        -1.73,
        4.0300000000000002,
        -3.8900000000000001,
        4.3899999999999997
      ],
      [ "c",
        -2.5899999999999999,
        0.42999999999999999,
        -5.04,
        -1.4399999999999999,
        -5.54,
        -4.0999999999999996
      ],
      [ "c",
        -0.42999999999999999,
        -2.7400000000000002,
        1.3,
        -5.2599999999999998,
        3.8900000000000001,
        -5.6900000000000004
      ],
      [ "c",
        1.9399999999999999,
        -0.35999999999999999,
        3.8900000000000001,
        0.65000000000000002,
        4.9000000000000004,
        2.2999999999999998
      ],
      [ "l",
        17.93,
        -4.8200000000000003
      ],
      [ "l",
        -1.3700000000000001,
        -6.8399999999999999
      ],
      [ "c",
        -4.8200000000000003,
        -0.79000000000000004,
        -8.9299999999999997,
        -4.75,
        -9.7899999999999991,
        -10.08
      ],
      [ "c",
        -1.1499999999999999,
        -6.6200000000000001,
        3.1000000000000001,
        -12.890000000000001,
        9.4299999999999997,
        -13.970000000000001
      ],
      [ "c",
        6.4100000000000001,
        -1.01,
        12.460000000000001,
        3.46,
        13.539999999999999,
        10.08
      ],
      [ "c",
        0.85999999999999999,
        5.1799999999999997,
        -1.5800000000000001,
        10.15,
        -5.6900000000000004,
        12.6
      ],
      [ "l",
        1.8700000000000001,
        6.1200000000000001
      ],
      [ "l",
        20.739999999999998,
        -2.8799999999999999
      ],
      [ "C",
        64.010000000000005,
        24.260000000000002,
        65.519999999999996,
        22.75,
        67.390000000000001,
        22.390000000000001
      ],
      [ "L",
        67.390000000000001,
        22.390000000000001
      ],
      [ "z" ],
      [ "M",
        33.909999999999997,
        5.1799999999999997
      ],
      [ "c",
        -3.46,
        0.57999999999999996,
        -5.7599999999999998,
        3.96,
        -5.1100000000000003,
        7.5599999999999996
      ],
      [ "c",
        0.57999999999999996,
        3.6000000000000001,
        3.8900000000000001,
        6.0499999999999998,
        7.2699999999999996,
        5.4699999999999998
      ],
      [ "c",
        3.46,
        -0.57999999999999996,
        5.7599999999999998,
        -3.96,
        5.1799999999999997,
        -7.5599999999999996
      ],
      [ "C",
        40.609999999999999,
        7.0499999999999998,
        37.369999999999997,
        4.6100000000000003,
        33.909999999999997,
        5.1799999999999997
      ],
      [ "z" ]
    ],
  "scaleX" : 3.0299999999999998,
  "scaleY" : 3.0299999999999998,
  "selectable" : true,
  "stroke" : null,
  "strokeWidth" : 1,
  "top" : 220,
  "type" : "path",
  "width" : 99
}
```

you would have this:

```
{ "angle" : 3,
  "fill" : "#00274D",
  "flipX" : false,
  "flipY" : false,
  "height" : 115,
  "left" : 353,
  "opacity" : 1,
  "overlayFill" : null,
  "path" : "http://example.com",
  "scaleX" : 3.0299999999999998,
  "scaleY" : 3.0299999999999998,
  "selectable" : true,
  "stroke" : null,
  "strokeWidth" : 1,
  "top" : 220,
  "type" : "path",
  "width" : 99
}
```

Notice how large that data is, and how relatively small it becomes by replacing path chunk with url.

And that's a representation of a very simple shape.

The only requirement here is to set object's "sourcePath" using `setSourcePath` method before calling `toDatalessObject`/`toDatalessJSON` on it ("sourcePath" is internally copied to "path").

Hope this clears things up a little.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the 'dataless' aspect now. That's great. But, I have not been able to load the result of JSON.stringify(canvas) back into the canvas. I have made a work around, but I would love to understand the right way to do it. Below is basically what I have tried and failed with:   `var js = JSON.stringify(canvas);    canvas.clear();     canvas.loadFromJSON(js);`    I get _reference error_   For my workaround, I save the JSON, then walk through it, look at each object's type, make a new fabric object of corresponding type, initialize it with the params from json, and then add it...

Comment: Hmm. `loadFromJSON` should work. Do you have a testcase I can look at?

Comment: yes, I put a little demo there: http://www.regiszaleman.com/testfabric/    Thank you so much!

Comment: Just replace `savedDataDLJSON = c1.toDatalessJSON()` with `savedDataDLJSON = JSON.stringify(c1.toDatalessJSON())`.

Comment: Thanks @kangax, I just did. Still not working. When I try to load the stringified datalessJSON or the sringified JSON, i get `camelize is not defined   in fabric/all-min.js:7`. hmmm... I wonder what I am doing wrong? and sorry for all the trouble...

Comment: Sorry, that was a bug in one of the previous versions. You seem to have 0.4.2. That bug was fixed in 0.4.9. It should work with latest one (0.4.12) — https://raw.github.com/kangax/fabric.js/04bb0aad66868cc6c1196f0f9843e2529d83a5e1/dist/all.js Or you can use minified version from github, but it's at 4.0.9; I forgot to upload minified 0.4.12, although you can always do it yourself following instructions in README.

Comment: @kangax I was able to load the saved json object but there seems to be a few issues with the loaded objects. I had created objects with 
        object.lockUniScaling=true;
        object.hasRotatingPoint = true; but now after the JSON is loaded these objects do not have these properties set accordingly. Instead they go back to their default behaviour. All I want is to load the objects as they were before saving. Without scaling and and with rotating point