# Loading canvas using JSON data results in empty output

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Am using background image and textbox in my canvas.

**Step 1:** Am creating canvas object using fabric JS in normal way.

```js
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
/* canvas background Image settings */
canvas.setBackgroundColor({source: imssrc, repeat: 'no-repeat'}, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
// text box, 120x60, without background image
var txtBox = new fabric.Textbox("A Great text to be rendered in the screen, wraped", {
  fontSize: 18,
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  textAlign: 'left',
  left: 20,
  top:20,
  right:20,
  bottom:20,
  width: 340,
  height: 510,
  fill:'#FFFFFF',
});
canvas.add(txtBox).setActiveObject(txtBox);

addHandler('sizepicker', function(obj) {
      setStyle(obj, 'fontSize', this.value);
    }, 'onchange');
addHandler('colorpicker', function(obj) {
      setStyle(obj, 'fill', this.value);
    }, 'onchange');
}
```

**Step 2:** Am generating JSON and going to next form

```js
var canvasjson = JSON.stringify( canvas.toDatalessJSON() );
document.getElementById('imgpath').value=o;
document.getElementById('canvasdata').value=canvasjson;
canvas.clear();
canvas.loadFromJSON(canvasjson, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

// If you want the file to be visible in the browser 
// - please modify the callback in javascript. All you
// need is to return the url to the file, you just saved 
// and than put the image in your browser.
var imgtxt=document.getElementById('imgpath').value;
var txt=$("#description").code();
$("#events-description").val(txt);
if(imgtxt.length!=0){
  $('form').submit();
  //        console.log(canvasjson);
  return false;
}
```

**Step 3:** I stored this form value in session. If user click this previous button am loading the content what user did in previous stage.

```js
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 5
});

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var object = JSON.parse(templateText); //use default json parser
canvas.loadFromJSON(templateText, function(){
            canvas.width = object.width;
            canvas.height = object.height;
});
canvas.renderAll();
```

My expected result is that the canvas needs to load from this JSON data but 
output is empty. I couldn't find any JS error also.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

My JSON data:

```
{
  "text":[
    {
      "text":"TOGETHER WITH THIER FAMILIES",
      "font":{
        "name":"Adamina",
        "size":"12",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"250"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"BRIDE NAME HERE",
      "font":{
        "name":"Monsieur La Doulaise Regular",
        "size":"34",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"280"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"TO",
      "font":{
        "name":"Adamina",
        "size":"14",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"300"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"GRROM NAME HERE",
      "font":{
        "name":"Adamina",
        "size":"34",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"320"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"CHURCH NAME HERE",
      "font":{
        "name":"Monsieur La Doulaise Regular",
        "size":"24",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"340"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"SATURDAY,  NOVEMBER 15TH, 2015",
      "font":{
        "name":"Monsieur La Doulaise Regular",
        "size":"24",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"360"
      }
    },
    {
      "text":"6:30 PM",
      "font":{
        "name":"Adamina",
        "size":"15",
        "spacing":"10",
        "alignment":"center",
        "color":"#F8E4C8"
      },
      "style":{
        "left":"180",
        "top":"380"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't know what mistake I did. Please help me.

Comment: If you know this question already exists, then I suggest you start there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading JSON in canvas with fabric.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886984/loading-json-in-canvas-with-fabric-js)

Comment: This issue was fixed. I just encode (json_encode) the input of canvas using php then load the canvas using loadFromJSON(). now it was working
Thank you guys.